# Clarification about path in windows and including files in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, path

I don't understand what does the dollar sign mean in a path in Windows 7 for example:

```
$(dir5)\include;
```

And also if I want to specify the location of some header files that I want to include inside my c++ project in Visual Studio. And the include folder is in my project folder. Should I write the path like:

```
\include\  or   \include    or    include\
```

And also if I'm using a third part dll file should I add its path in the environment variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(foo) is a macro for a folder name. Look at project properties... VC++ Directories... Include Directories... < Edit > from the drop list... Macros button.  This provides you a list of all defined macros.

$(ProjectDir)include will point to a project specific include folder.

Macros that end in 'Dir' usually end with a path separator so $(foo)subdir works fine.  No need for extra path separator as in: $(foo)\subdir.

Comment: Sometimes I see % is used in place of $. What is the difference? Is that an old practice? I am talking about as used in VS C++ project properties. In "Additional Include Directories".